# Build an Docker image with Mac M1, push it to Docker Hub : can not use that image on Win 10

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, windows-10, apple-m1, kompose

```
docker: Error response form daemon: 
image with reference qwerty22/kube-kompose:pok-0 was found
but does not match the specified platform:
wanted windows/amd64, actual : linux/arm64.
```

This was new to me. I thought Docker/standard images are "universal".  But now it seems that you need to build an image for each platform - to run on ?

Example image was kubernetes-kompose from [https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose]

EDIT: I was trying to run that image on Win 10 and Docker desktop.

So the question is: Can I build a Docker image with my Mac, push the image to Docker Hub, pull image to a Win 10, and run it there?

I did not seem to succeed on that.

Answer (score 3):

The OS architecture of the build and the run must be compatible.

You should turn on Linux containers on Docker desktop. To do that, right-click on Docker desktop icon and select `Switch to Linux Containers` from the menu.
For more details check [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux).

Another way is to build the image on your Mac M1 for `amd64` like this:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 --push -t <registry>/<project-id>/<image>
```

because the docker images built with Apple Silicon are ARM-based architecture and this can create issues when deploying the images to a Linux or Windows-based `amd64` environment.

Comment: I was not able to test "buildx", because by Mac and Docer Hub can not talk to each other, obviously because Docker on Mac side is somehow corrupted (wants some mysterious key chain password ???)

Comment: Did you solve anyway your issue with the 1st method? [Off-topic from the original question] The key chain pwd should be the same of the one used in your login. If not. you can reset it from "Applications folder > Utilities > Keychain Access" or from "Keychain Access > Settings"